# Converting int to string reduces time complexity of calculating its length

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity

The following code block:

```
Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
int n=in.nextInt();
//converting the integer to string and calculating
//its length reduces the complexity
//to O(n) as compared to O(n^2)
String str=Integer.toString(n);
int length=str.length();length-=1;
```

I found [this code here](http://qa.geeksforgeeks.org/10856/you-are-asked-to-square-every-digit-of-a-number).

My question is how does changing the int to string reduce the time complexity?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking to explain an incorrect statement by some random person on the internet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The author of that code claims it reduces complexity compared to another solution posted:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  int num,d,rev=0;

  cin>>num;

 // reverse a no.
  while(num!=0)
  {
    d=num%10;
    rev=rev*10+d;
    num=num/10;
  }

  // using digits of reversed no.
  while(rev!=0)
  {
    d=rev%10;
    cout<<d*d; // printing square 
    rev=rev/10;
  }

 return 0;
}
```

This is false, both solutions have the same complexity, `O(n)`.

Answer (score 0):

Even finding the length of the integer using a simple `while` loop is O(n), not O(n^2).

Consider the following snippet:

```
while(n!=0)
{
    n/=10;
    ++count;
}
```